# Reduce android apk size by trimming OpenCV library

Tags: android, c++, opencv

Am using the OpenCV library for my project and after integration it produces .so files for armeabi, armeabi-v7a, mips and x86 architectures. My apk file size is around 60MB. I searched google and find a way of publishing multiple apk for different architecture. But it would be better if i can trim the file size. Please suggest.

Comment: Check your res files especially the images on drawable folder.

Comment: No problem from drawable side. Its having only necessary images. Is that possible to remove unwanted .so files

Comment: Aren't you using OpenCV Manager for managing the libraries?

Comment: @bikz05.  I came to know about that. But i don't want to let the user to divert. Is that a better solution?

Comment: Yes, it will automatically install the respective version for the device architecture. As, per these slides [link](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1EO_1kijgBg_BsjNp2ymk-aarg-0K279_1VZRcPplSuk/present#slide=id.p), you can reduce a 20 MB apk file to less than .5 MB. It has other advantages also, just read the slides.

Comment: @bikz05 can you please repost the link. currently it is dead.. much thanks

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV is probably built as a set of .so files, e.g. Machine Learning produces a -ml library. Only include the libraries which you actually need. You're almost certainly not going to need all of them.

Comment: the project generated several so files. Shall i delete the unused so files.